# Showing all decimal numbers in C

Tags: c

So I'm trying to print my my data from a file that was already given to me. In our data most of the numbers have 9 decimal places. A starter code was given to me by my teacher and when I try to print the data it only prints up to 6 decimal places. So the last 3 digits don't show up in the output. Also I have tried to write the number of decimal places like `%.9f` but surprisingly the last three digits are  different. For example the number in my data is `1.900195512` while the printed number (set to 9 decimal places) is `1.900195479`.

My code is:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// Declare constants

// Name of file that stores our raw data
#define FILE_NAME "data_1.csv"

// Data size
#define MAX_ROWS 20
#define MAX_COLUMNS 20

// Main entry point for the program
int main(void) {
    // Decalred variables
    int rowIndex = 0;
    int columnIndex = 0;
    float rawData[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS]; // 2-dimensional array to store our 
    raw data
    // Misc variables used for reading the data from the file
    float tempfloat = 0.0F;
    float tmp = 0.0F;
    char newline = ' ';

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Open the file for reading 
    FILE *infp;
    infp = fopen(FILE_NAME, "r");

    // Check for errors and exit if found
    if (infp == NULL) {
        printf("Error: failed to open %s for reading\n", FILE_NAME);
        return(1);
    }

    // Read the file into the data structure
    for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < MAX_ROWS; rowIndex++) {
        // Read up until the last value
        for (columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < MAX_COLUMNS - 1; columnIndex++) {
            if (fscanf_s(infp, "%f,", &tempfloat) != EOF) {
                rawData[rowIndex][columnIndex] = tempfloat;
            } else {
                printf("Error: incorrect file format at row %d, col %d.\n", rowIndex + 1, columnIndex + 1);
                return(1);
            }
        }

        // Read the last value and the newline char
        if (fscanf_s(infp, "%f%c", &tempfloat, &newline) != EOF) {
            // Check if the last character in the line was a \n otherwise an error occured.
            //Xiao: I have added newline != '\n'
            if (newline != '\0' && newline != '\r' && newline != '\n') {
                printf("Error: incorrect file format at line %d. did not find a newline.\n", rowIndex + 1);
                return(1);
            } else {
                rawData[rowIndex][columnIndex] = tempfloat;
            }

            // Reset the character before the next read. 
            newline = ' ';
        }
    }
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Print out the rawdata array
    printf(" --- RAW DATA ---\n");
    for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < MAX_ROWS; rowIndex++) {
        // Read up until the last value
        for (columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < MAX_COLUMNS; columnIndex++) {
            printf("%.9f ", rawData[rowIndex][columnIndex]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    // Exit
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Read http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Floating point precision.

Comment: This would be a better question if you reduced the code down to a minimal example that's runnable without a data file. It'd probably be little more than a call to `scanf` and `printf`.

Comment: Have you investigated using `double` instead of `float`? (in addition to all the other pointers in that direction above).

Comment: You should learn a little about how decimals are represented as floating point values in a computer's memory.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch.: Awesome resource...sometimes let me know about other resources too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `float` type does not have enough precision for 9 accurate decimal places. You should use the `double` type, which you can scan with `%lf`.

Also do not compare the return value of `fscanf()` to `EOF` to detect failure, invalid input may cause `0` to be returned.  Just verify the number of successful conversions returned by `fscanf()`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// Declare constants

// Name of file that stores our raw data
#define FILE_NAME "data_1.csv"

// Data size
#define MAX_ROWS 20
#define MAX_COLUMNS 20

// Main entry point for the program
int main(void) {
    // Decalred variables
    int rowIndex = 0;
    int columnIndex = 0;
    double rawData[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS]; // 2-dimensional array to store our 
    raw data
    // Misc variables used for reading the data from the file
    double tempfloat = 0.0;
    double tmp = 0.0;
    char newline;

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Open the file for reading 
    FILE *infp;
    infp = fopen(FILE_NAME, "r");

    // Check for errors and exit if found
    if (infp == NULL) {
        printf("Error: failed to open %s for reading\n", FILE_NAME);
        return(1);
    }

    // Read the file into the data structure
    for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < MAX_ROWS; rowIndex++) {
        // Read up until the last value
        for (columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < MAX_COLUMNS - 1; columnIndex++) {
            if (fscanf_s(infp, "%lf,", &tempfloat) == 1) {
                rawData[rowIndex][columnIndex] = tempfloat;
            } else {
                printf("Error: incorrect file format at row %d, col %d.\n", rowIndex + 1, columnIndex + 1);
                return 1;
            }
        }

        // Read the last value and the newline char
        if (fscanf_s(infp, "%lf%c", &tempfloat, &newline) == 2) {
            // Check if the last character in the line was a \n otherwise an error occured.
            //Xiao: I have added newline != '\n'
            if (newline != '\r' && newline != '\n') {
                printf("Error: incorrect file format at line %d. did not find a newline.\n", rowIndex + 1);
                return 1;
            } else {
                rawData[rowIndex][columnIndex] = tempfloat;
            }
        }
    }
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Print out the rawdata array
    printf(" --- RAW DATA ---\n");
    for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < MAX_ROWS; rowIndex++) {
        // Read up until the last value
        for (columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < MAX_COLUMNS; columnIndex++) {
            printf("%.9f ", rawData[rowIndex][columnIndex]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    // Exit
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can break your problem down into a much more concise example to help isolate the problem. You are attempting to get 9-digit precision out of a type `float`, that is only good for 6-7. To improve your accuracy, you need to use type `double` instead.

When you read any user input **always, always** validate the return of the function used, and any constraints on the value (none in you case).

A short implementation correcting the issue could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    double d = 0.0;

    printf ("Enter value: ");
    if (scanf ("%lf", &d) == 1)
        printf ("Your value : %.9f\n", d);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/scanf_double
Enter value: 1.900195512
Your value : 1.900195512
```

Look over the answers and comments and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

`float` is not accurate after 7 places. Use `double` instead

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    float f;
    double d;
    scanf("%f",&f);
    scanf("%lf",&d);
    printf("%.9f\n",f);
    printf("%.9lf\n",d);
    return 0;
}


Input:
0.123456789      // float variable i.e. f
0.123456789      // double variable i.e. d

Output:
0.123456791     //  float precision
0.123456789     //  double precision
```